# QT 5.2.0 getOpenFileName slow

Tags: c++, qt

When calling getOpenFileName, the function very often hangs for 5 seconds or so. The actual call is:

```
  QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
     tr("Open XML"),"D:\\xml_reader\\data\\",tr("XML Files (*.xml *.*)"));
```

The folder I'm sending it to contains only one file, so it's not because of file count.
I've tried it in both Debug and Release, they are both experiencing the same issue.

Looking online I've seen others with a similar issue, but no resolution.
I've used other versions of QT in the past and never experienced the issue.

Comment: Is D: a network drive? Step into getOpenFileName() to see what's dragging it.

Comment: I found out that Qt's file dialog becomes unusable if there is some other task that demands a lot of attention in GUI thread. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Haven't yet been able to find the root cause of the issue

Comment: I experience the same delay with qt5.5 on mac osx el capitan on the first time the file dialog is open per application execution, regardless of optimizations. No solution known.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across the same problem and the fix for me was to remove a bad network location from my quick access list on the left hand side of windows file explorer.
The network location was not reachable anymore.

It would lag in release and in debug mode, both when actually selecting a file and when hitting the cancel or close buttons.

The dialog would open fast, but then after closing the dialog my app would lag for 2-5 seconds before continuing to the next instruction which I confirmed by stepping through the code in debug and by having a visual cue open on the next line in release.

What finally helped me realize the problem was when it happened again in a completely different app not made by me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Do not run your app under debugger.
2. When you load your app you may force to load Comdlg32.dll.

p.s. QT - is QuickTime, you are using Qt

**Special "summary" update for @JohnNeuhaus:**

*Q*: Why getOpenFileName is slow?

*A*: Reason: `Comdlg32.dll`is delay-loaded library that starts to load on first `getOpenFileName` call. This load time is big. Dynamic linkage time may be increased if debugger is connected (because it is necessary to load .pdb).

Workaround: directly load `Comctl32.dll' at the start of application:

```
QLibrary lib( "Comctl32.dll" );`
lib.setLoadHints( QLibrary::ResolveAllSymbolsHint );
lib.load();
```

Comment: I've ran Qt apps under debugger before without this issue. It must have been introduced in Qt 5.2 or after 4.8

Comment: You wrong. It has same lags on first dialog show on both qt4 and qt5. I researched this ;)

Comment: @SaZ "Do not run your app under debugger" is never an acceptable answer to a performance issue.  Running it in the debugger will likely result in slower performance, but that's the price you pay for debugging.  That's like telling someone to use a text editor if they have an Intellisense problem in VS.

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus we are talking about profiling, not debugging. You must profile under release version (with code optimization on) and without debugger. Otherwise, profiling results will be invalid. Customers will not use debug build of you application with turned on debugger.

Comment: @SaZ According to the question, we are not talking about either specifically. The poster simply stated that a function call was slow and that they tried both Debug and Release.

Comment: @SaZ And while profiling in release with optimizations gives you more accurate timing, the loss of debug information limits your ability to see what's going on at the bottlenecks. Therefore, profiling in debug remains a valid approach, though best used in tandem with the product as shipped.

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus we are talking about real reason. Don't change context of a question. Summary (reasons of slowness), according to priority: 1) Time for dynamic linking of `Comctl32.dll` 2) Debugger tries to load .pdb's 3) Compiler optimization.

Comment: @SaZ How did I change the context? OP didn't say they were profiling the code, you did. "Do not run your app under debugger" is a proscription, not a reason. It was given with no qualifications. It is a bad answer to "X is running slow" that rejects a technical analysis in favor of "you're doing it wrong."

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus I don't want to explain a lot, if you have any questions - you may create your own. I extended my answer, because you are in offtopic area.

Comment: Qt does not stand for "Quick Time"
Q was chosen because the original developer liked how it looked in his emacs font and the "t "was added to stand for "toolkit"